# Tidyquant: How do I assign the stock type to an existing list?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyquant

I have a list of stocks in the SP500 index. How would I assign categories type to each stocks?

Current output:

```
library(tidyquant)
tq_index('SP500')$symbol

[1] "MSFT"   "AAPL"   "AMZN"   "BRK.B"  "FB" [...]
```

Expected:

```
symbol type
MSFT   Technology
AAPL   Technology
AMZN   Technology
BRK.B  Financials
FB     Technology
```

Comment: Try using `[`, this should give what you want: `tq_index('SP500')[c("symbol", "sector")]`

Comment: @DiceboyT Will try it

Comment: @DiceboyT Amazing! THANKS!